# What are the uses of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock?

Tags: c++, c++11, time, clock, c++-chrono

At first I thought it can be used for performance measurements. But it is [said](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) that `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` may be not steady (`is_steady` may be `false`). It is also said that `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` may even be an alias of `std::chrono::system_clock` which is generally not steady. So I can't measure time intervals with this type of clock because at any moment the clock may be adjusted and my measurements will be wrong.

At the same time I can't convert time points of `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` to calendar time because it doesn't have `to_time_t` method. So I can't get the *real time* with this type of clock either.

Then what can `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` be used for?

Comment: Well, since it may be an alias it cannot be steady, since `system_clock` is not steady, as you point out. It's an optional clock, that's it. If an implementation can't support it, you get the `system_clock` in its place. But, if you're in luck, you got yourself a spiffy, shiny, high resolution clock.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are none.

Sorry, [my bad](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm).

If you are tempted to use `high_resolution_clock`, choose `steady_clock` instead.  On libc++ and VS `high_resolution_clock` is a type alias of `steady_clock` anyway.

On gcc `high_resolution_clock` is a type alias of `system_clock` and I've seen more than one use of `high_resolution_clock::to_time_t` on this platform (which is wrong).

**Do** use `<chrono>`.  But there are parts of `<chrono>` that you should avoid.

- Don't use `high_resolution_clock`.
- Avoid uses of `.count()` and `.time_since_epoch()` unless there is no other way to get the job done.
- Avoid `duration_cast` unless the code won't compile without it, and you desire truncation-towards-zero behavior.
- Avoid explicit conversion syntax if an implicit conversion compiles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think high_resolution_clock still can be legally used in this way: `typedef typename std::conditional<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, std::chrono::steady_clock>::type hr_steady_clock;`.

Comment: @anton_rh:  True enough.  For every implementation I'm aware of, that is a complicated way to say `using hr_steady_clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "Avoid uses of `.count()` and `.time_since_epoch()`" part? What caveats are hidden behind these functions?

Comment: @Julien:  `.count()` and `.time_since_epoch()` are much like `reinterpret_cast`.  They change the type so drastically as to change the meaning of the value.  Sometimes that is necessary.  But if you can avoid it, `chrono` will catch more logical errors for you at compile time by making sure your use of the time units is consistent.

Comment: One reason why everyone is using `.count()` is probably that all the examples on cppreference.com use it as well. E.g. [`chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)

Comment: Yep.  As we transition to C++20, `.count()` should become a lot less necessary.  For example you'll be able to print out your durations without `.count()`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Great if all you want is a time-stamp. But if all you wanted was a timestamp,  you wouldn't be using high_resolution_clock. How do you answer the question of "how long?" if you don't use duration and/or count?

Comment: I use `steady_clock` for timings that I expect to be brief, and otherwise `system_clock`.  "Brief" is a vague term.  Call it 1s or 1min.  I _do_ use `duration`.  But I only use `duration_cast` if I desire truncate towards zero behavior.  Don't use `duration_cast` to (for example) convert seconds to milliseconds.  Implicit conversion will work fine for that.  Use `duration_cast` to convert milliseconds to seconds.  Don't use `.count()` unless you need it for a print statement.  And even then, I prefer C++20, or https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h instead.

Comment: chrono video 1h tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: anyone asking for an actual strict real time (not to be mistaken for wall time) have to fall-back to non-portable solutions... some platforms don't even have any built-in support in software API (use  assembler!) or even in hardware (you'll need an external time device)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that single uses of the high res clock *could* lie.

If your algorithm makes use of *many* measurements then any error should average-out and you should be able to measure very small intervals.

I've used the high resolution clock to build timelines in network events where otherwise my intervals would have all been `0`. :)

Finally, consider that while your system clock might not be steady, *if* your high res clock is stead, that greatly simplifies some games you have to play to make sure time always flows forwards.

In summary, yeah, it can fail, but when you have it, it's very helpful. Lots of samples are your friends. :)