# What is the most accurate way to measure the time to perform a function, and what is its accuracy?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project that involves recording the time that a certain function takes to run one hundred times. I'm using a solution using the  library but I seem to remember that there is a more accurate way that uses the processor's internal timing system for very accurate timing. Is there a better solution, and what's the uncertainty on the result?

Comment: What library are you using? Perhaps that library is also using the processor's internal timing system.

Comment: No way to answer in the general case. You'll need to specify the target OS and probably hardware.

Comment: Warning: `high-resolution_clock` is weakly specified to the point where it can be dangerous to use. [Here's what one of the people most responsible for the chrono library has to say about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426832/what-are-the-uses-of-stdchronohigh-resolution-clock)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Run the thing you want to measure many times and divide the measured time by that number. The more often you run it, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the chrono library will be your most accurate option likely. There is no way to know the resolution and accuracy of the clock without knowing exactly your setup, but you can assume it's small enough for all practical uses.