# CUDA: Matrix inversion slower on GPU than on CPU

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, gpu, matrix-inverse

I have a stable, simple Gauss-Jordan algorithm for calculating the matrix inversion on the CPU. I tried to transfer this algorithm to the GPU, it works fine, but the speed has dropped significantly, about 10 times. I understand that I am not well versed in C++ and CUDA, and I would be glad to hear some advice. Thanks in advance.

Console:

```
matrix size = 88; CPU time = 6531 mcs; GPU time = 52806 mcs;
```

Here is the code for the CPU:

```
void GaussJordanInverse(float* original, float* temp, float* singular, float* bigmatrix, int size) {
    //create temp
    //create singular matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            temp[i * size + j] = original[i * size + j];
            singular[i * size + j] = 0; 
        }
        singular[i * size + i] = 1;
    }
    //create big matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + j] = temp[i * size + j];
            bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + j + size] = singular[i * size + j];
        }
    }
    //direct
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * size; i++) bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + i] = bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + i] / temp[k * size + k];
        for (int i = k + 1; i < size; i++) {
            float K = bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + k] / bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + k];
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * size; j++)bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + j] = bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + j] - bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + j] * K;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                temp[i * size + j] = bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + j];
            }
        }
    }
    //indirect
    for (int k = size - 1; k > -1; k--)
    {
        for (int i = 2 * size - 1; i > -1; i--) bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + i] = bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + i] / temp[k * size + k];
        for (int i = k - 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            float K = bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + k] / bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + k];
            for (int j = 2 * size - 1; j > -1; j--)
                bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + j] = bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + j] - bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + j] * K;
        }
    }
    //cut
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            singular[i * size + j] = bigmatrix[i * (size * 2) + j + size];
            original[i * size + j] = singular[i * size + j];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the GPU:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>
#ifndef __CUDACC__  
#define __CUDACC__
#endif
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include "matrixconversion.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

__global__ void create(float* original, float* temp, float* singular, float* bigmatrix, int size) {
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    //create singular matrix
    if (x < size && y < size)
    {
        temp[x * size + y] = original[x * size + y];
        if (x == y) singular[x * size + y] = 1;
        //singular[x * size + y] = 0;
        //create big matrix
        bigmatrix[x * (2 * size) + y] = temp[x * size + y];
        bigmatrix[x * (2 * size) + y + size] = singular[x * size + y];
    }
}
__global__ void direct_kernel(float* temp, float* bigmatrix, int size, int k) {
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (x < 2 * size) {
        bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + x] /= temp[k * size + k];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (x >= k + 1 && x < size * 2) {
        float K = bigmatrix[x * (size * 2) + k] / bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + k];
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * size; j++) {
            bigmatrix[x * (size * 2) + j] -= bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + j] * K;
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (x < size) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            temp[x * size + j] = bigmatrix[x * (size * 2) + j];
        }
    }
}
__global__ void indirect_kernel(float* temp, float* bigmatrix, int size, int k) {
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (x < 2 * size) {
        bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + x] /= temp[k * size + k];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (x < k&& x >= 0) {
        float K = bigmatrix[x * (size * 2) + k] / bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + k];
        for (int j = 2 * size - 1; j > -1; j--) {
            bigmatrix[x * (size * 2) + j] -= bigmatrix[k * (size * 2) + j] * K;
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

__global__ void cut(float* original, float* singular, float* bigmatrix, int size) {
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (x < size && y < size) {
        singular[x * size + y] = bigmatrix[x * (size * 2) + y + size];
        original[x * size + y] = singular[x * size + y];
    }
}

void GPUInverse(float* copy, float* original, int size, long int* time) {
    Copy1DFloat(copy, original, size);
    //set kernels
    int tr = 16;
    int bl = (int)ceil(size / tr);
    dim3 grid_size(16, 16);
    dim3 block_size(bl, bl);
    //create temp
    float* d_copy, * d_temp, * d_singular, * d_bigmatrix;
    //memory
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_copy, size * size * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_temp, size * size * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_singular, size * size * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_bigmatrix, size * (size * 2) * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemset(d_copy, 0, size * size * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemset(d_temp, 0, size * size * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemset(d_singular, 0, size * size * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemset(d_bigmatrix, 0, size * (2 * size) * sizeof(float));
    //to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_copy, copy, size * size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    //fill temp
    create <<<grid_size, block_size >>> (d_copy, d_temp, d_singular, d_bigmatrix, size);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //direct
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        direct_kernel <<<(2 * size + 255) / 256, 256 >>> (d_temp, d_bigmatrix, size, k);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
    //indirect
    for (int k = size - 1; k > -1; k--) {
        indirect_kernel <<<(2 * size + 255) / 256, 256 >>> (d_temp, d_bigmatrix, size, k);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
    //cut
    cut <<<grid_size, block_size >>> (d_copy, d_singular, d_bigmatrix, size);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    *time = duration.count();
    //from device
    cudaMemcpy(copy, d_copy, size * size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //clean

    cudaFree(d_copy);
    cudaFree(d_temp);
    cudaFree(d_singular);
    cudaFree(d_bigmatrix);
}
```

Comment: For [coalescing](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory) you should use `threadIdx.x` for the inner dimension of the matrices when possible. I.e. exchanging `x` and `y` in your kernels could potentially give some easy speedup.

Comment: Offtopic, but FYI [Avoid `high_resolution_clock`, use `steady_clock` for benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37440647/10107454), [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)

Comment: `__syncthreads()` only synchronizes among each block of threads. Your usage looks like you are assuming that it synchronizes the whole grid.

Comment: The old-school way of getting a grid-sync is just a kernel boundary (i.e. split your kernels into more kernels). Alternatively you can use the newer [cooperative groups API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#grid-synchronization).

Comment: Avoid `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` between kernel calls. As long as all kernels are launched on the same (default) stream, there is no need to synchronize between them.

Comment: While your launch configuration for `direct_kernel` and `indirect_kernel` looks fine, `block_size` and `grid_size` seem weird. Why not have a static `dim3 block_size(16, 16);` and a dynamic `dim3 grid_size((size + block_size.x - 1) / block_size.x, (size + block_size.y - 1) / block_size.y);`, or even better for coalescing due to warp size: `dim3 block_size(32, 8);`

Comment: The GPU solution will probably never be faster than the CPU solution for `size == 88`, there is just not enough parallelism. If at all, you will need to compare bigger problem sizes. But as you have sequential loops on the host that also grow with `size` (i.e. total of kernel launch overheads will also grow with `size`), I'm generally not too optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [paleonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10107454/paleonix) for your advices. Indeed, the more data you have, the better you can see the difference in speedup between the CPU and GPU. In addition, the removal of `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` helped to speed up the work even more. Now the console looks like this:

```
matrix size = 88; CPU time = 7096 mcs; GPU time = 418 mcs;
matrix size = 1000; CPU time = 9834535 mcs; GPU time = 4347 mcs;
```