# C++ - Why does this return a segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to test and calculate how much time merge and insertion sort take for sorting an array.

As you can see, I'm using rand() to generate random integers and for whatever reason if I do int asize = rand() % 100 (or any small number) it works, but I need bigger numbers to test these two algorithms.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void generateArray(int arr[], int asize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < asize; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
}

void insertionSort(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        int key = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

void merger(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right)
{
    int n1 = mid - left + 1;
    int n2 = right - mid;
    int leftArr[n1];
    int rightArr[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
        leftArr[i] = arr[left + i];
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
        rightArr[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = left;

    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (leftArr[i] <= rightArr[j]) {
            arr[k] = leftArr[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = rightArr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = leftArr[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = rightArr[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

        mergeSort(arr, left, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right);

        merger(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    // % 1000 to generate a value between 0 and 999
    int asize = rand();
    int forMerge[asize];
    generateArray(forMerge, asize);
    auto forInsertion = forMerge;
    auto startMerge = high_resolution_clock::now();
    mergeSort(forMerge, 0, asize - 1);
    auto stopMerge = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto durationMerge = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stopMerge - startMerge);
    cout << "Time to finish merge sort: " << durationMerge.count() << endl;
    // printArray(forMerge, asize);
    auto startInsertion = high_resolution_clock::now();
    insertionSort(forInsertion, asize);
    auto stopInsertion = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto durationInstertion = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stopMerge - startMerge);
    cout <<"Time to finish instertion sort: " << durationInstertion.count() << endl;
    // printArray(forInsertion, asize);
}
```

I tried to int asize = rand() % 99; and it works, but I need bigger numbers since I want to test these different algorithms.

Comment: Worst thing you could do was done: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;` (and more really bad things). I am definitely out in investigating about that.

Comment: You are limited by your program stack size when using local variables. It's usualy few MB

Comment: `int n1 = mid - left + 1; int n2 = right - mid; int leftArr[n1]; int rightArr[n2];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time value, not a runtime value.

Comment: please do not use VLAs (variable length arrays). They are not standard c++. Some compilers allow them as extensions, but c++ has `std::vector` that you should use

Comment: I'd recommend you learn how to use a debugger so you know what's failing. Been a while since I've done anything with C or C++, but segfault usually means you're accessing memory your application doesn't own. I suspect it's this line: `int forMerge[asize];` and you need to allocate memory for your array.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ could you please explain why? I'm a newbie in C++ :(

Comment: please do not use `std::high_resolution_clock`. Its one of those c++-quirks that appears like a good idea but in fact isnt. ["The high_resolution_clock is not implemented consistently across different standard library implementations, and its use should be avoided."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock). Use `std::steady_clock` to measure time

Comment: @Stonework1025 [Your code fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/WxKTahncT), for the reasons given.  Stop using "online competitive coding" websites to learn C++.

Comment: Heck, one of the creators of `high_resolution_clock` [literally said "My bad"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37440647/4581301) when asked how to use it properly.

Comment: @stone Sure, here you go: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?r=Saves_AllUserSaves), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h?r=Saves_AllUserSaves), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard?r=Saves_AllUserSaves), and maybe more stuff. But actually you seem to need a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?r=Saves_AllUserSaves). HTH

Comment: it wont fix the segfault, but you should pay attention to warnings, more often than not they point to issues in your code https://godbolt.org/z/6G7831aYx

Comment: Apart from the inconsistent implementation of the "high resolution clock" and the non-standard use of "variable length arrays" (arrays whose dimensions are stated at run-time) (and assuming your code DOES compile in your platform), you need to know WHERE is the segmentation fault occurring (although the real cause will probably be in other place).

Comment: Fortunately the solution for most of your dynamically-sized array needs is dead simple: `std::vector`.  The `vector` is easily automatically allocated (so it lives on the limited-in-size "stack") but it [owns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49024982/4581301) a dynamically allocated array (which sits in the much larger "heap"). `vector` is one of the most useful tools in C++, so get familiar with it early and start saving time.

Comment: [And here are a few notes on `rand`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY)

Comment: Looks like this code comes from geeksforgeeks website. That website really teaches bad programming habits. I would recommend you learn some fundamental stuff about the language and then start learning DS and Algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `forMerge` is being allocated on the stack. Stack size is not unlimited; typically it's only a few megabytes. Large arrays should be allocated on the heap instead.

If you rewrite it like this, you'll see it works for any size:

```
int asize = rand() % 1000000;
int *forMerge = new int[asize];
```

Or even better:

```
int asize = rand() % 1000000;
std::vector<int> forMerge(asize);
```

By the way, you shouldn't use `rand()` to generate large numbers in portable programs, since it generates values between 0 and RAND_MAX, and RAND_MAX is not guaranteed to be greater than 32767.

Comment: it works! thank you very much for everything!

Comment: For fun, here's an implementation I did that randomly generates an int array and populates it with numbers. https://www.onlinegdb.com/_Tm4cYonk

Answer (score -4):

Right after creating the asize variable in the second line of main, put the following statement: "printf("asize %d\n", asize);". You'll see that it has a random number between 1 and 2 billion. The next instruction tries to open an array with this amount of data. This causes Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Try a smaller amount: int asize = rand() % 1000000;

And allocate memory: int * forMerge = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * asize);

Comment: `asize` could be  0 through 32k. The creation of the array sets up the potential for a stack overflow. What comes of a stack overflow is undefined. Could result in a seg fault, but also could make the computer start playing Liberace's Greatest Hits. Of all of the many ways to dynamically allocate an array, `malloc` is the one you should reach for last.

Comment: asize depends on your stack size. if your int is 8 bytes than asize can reach stacksize / 8. But if you allocate memory, It depends on your virtual memory size / 8.

Comment: I am struggling to understand that comment. The value of `asize` will be between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, which can be any value 32767 or greater. It has nothing to do with the size of an `int`, though it probably did back in the 1970s, and nothing to do with virtual memory.

Comment: What is causing SegmentationFault is the copy of a int array to the stack, in the folowing line `int forMerge[asize];`. The stack must have sizeof(int) * asize bytes to alocate this array. If you allocate memory `int *forMerge = new int[asize];`or `int * forMerge = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * asize)`, the limite will no be your stack size but yout memory size.