# Casting double chrono::seconds into millisecond

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, milliseconds, seconds

I have simple function:

```cpp
void foo(std::chrono::milliseconds ms) {
    std::cout << ms.count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

And next I'm calling them like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    boo(3s);
    boo(1h);
    boo(100ms);
}
```

Output is simple:

```
3000 milliseconds
3600000 milliseconds
100 milliseconds
```

But, what if I want to use this function like this:

```
boo(3.5s);
boo(0.5s);
boo(0.3days);
```

Then I have compile error.
So, I can write function who receive `chrono::duration`:

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo(std::chrono::duration<T> duration) {
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

And then `3.5s` will work, but `1h` or `3.5h` doesn't work.
So, question, can I write universal function which convert any of `1s`/`1.s`/`1m`/`1.5m`/`1h`/`1.5h`/etc into milliseconds?
Maybe I can create overloaded operators for `chrono::seconds`/hours? Or just cast, cast, cast?

Comment: Step 1: Read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/symbol_index/chrono_literals). Step 2: Figure out what "days" should *actually* be.

Comment: Don't say "doesn't work". Do say the *exact* errors you're getting and show the code that generated them.

Comment: Hmm, compile error, i think ?
main.cpp:17:9: error: could not convert ‘std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""s(3.5e+0l)’ from ‘duration>’ to ‘duration>’
   17 |     boo(3.5s);
i mean, im read the documentation, but, its question about tricks, not about "how to use"

Comment: I don't see `days` being defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/symbol_index/chrono_literals)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper function template definition should take the period as a template parameter too:

```cpp
template <class Rep, class Period>
void boo(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> duration) {
    
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration)
                     .count()
              << " milliseconds\n";
}
```

Or in C++20, don't call `.count()` and let it print the unit automatically:

```cpp
template <class Rep, class Period>
void boo(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> duration) {
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration)
              << '\n';
}
```

I have no clue about the `days` literal though. Never seen it, but the rest of them will work.

```cpp
int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    boo(3s);
    boo(1h);
    boo(100ms);

    boo(3.5s);
    boo(0.5s);
    boo(std::chrono::days(1) * 0.3); // what I got working
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z51Tqjdoq)

Comment: And yes, thank you, it work, strange, but im trying this before (template with two params), but, maybe im lost something, and it doesnt was work. Good!

Comment: @Illusion You're welcome! Great that it worked out!

Answer (score 2):

Converting a duration to a number is easier than you think!

If you **divide a duration by a duration**, you get a numeric value.  The result, mathematically speaking and respected by `std::chrono`, has no unit.

In your case, to get the number of milliseconds, simply divide **any duration** by **one millisecond**.

```
template <class Rep, class Period>
void foo(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> duration) {
    std::cout << duration / 1ms << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

[See it work in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5bG1WhrPf)

*It should be noted that the author of `std::chrono` explicitly recommends that [`.count()` and `duration_cast` should only be used as a last resort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37440647/16287).*

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/duration-class?view=msvc-170), we can include two template parameters for the function with the conversion. This is because we want to make the template function general so we need to tell it what type and ratio we're passing.

```
template<class R, class T>
void foo(std::chrono::duration<R, T> duration) {
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

As per another reference for the literals, floating point only works on [seconds](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s), [minutes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22min), and [hours](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22h). As for [days](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22d) and [years](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22y), it only works using unsigned long long. So this should already work:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    foo(3.5s);
    foo(3.5min);
    foo(3.5h);
}
```

However, if we want to use the same notation for days and years, we need to create our own custom literal operator. However, note that we cannot do it with the same reserved operators. We need to add underscores to the operator name. They're more or less like this:

```
constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds operator ""_y(long double y) noexcept
{
    return std::chrono::milliseconds((unsigned long long) (y * 31556952000));
}

constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds operator ""_d(long double d) noexcept
{
    return std::chrono::milliseconds((unsigned long long) (d * 86400000));
}
```

After adding these operators, this should work:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    foo(3.5s);
    foo(3.5min);
    foo(3.5h);
    foo(3.5_d);
    foo(3.5_y);
}
```