# How can I measure time duration of memory allocation in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, time-measurement

Any allocation of integers I try (varying the size of the array), the resulted time is still 0 NANOseconds.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>


using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int* memory_allocation()
{
  int *allocated_ints = new int[1000000];
  return allocated_ints;
}


int main()
{
   high_resolution_clock::time_point t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();

   int *p = memory_allocation();

   high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
   
   nanoseconds ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t1 - t0);
   std::cout << ns.count() << "ns\n";

   delete[] p;

   return 0;
}
```

Also, I tried encapsulating the memory allocation in a 1000000 million for loop, but the issue is that, I also have to deallocate it because of the heap space, resulting in also measuring the time for the 'delete' operation.

Is it really possible to be this small? If yes, is there any other way I can measure it?

Comment: Allocation is an operating system task, and most modern desktop OSes will use a lazy allocation scheme. Only giving physical memory when the memory is actually accessed and triggers a page fault.

Comment: benchmarking is unfortunately not that simple. You should use a tool/library dedicated for benchmarking, eg https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: Compilers are generally pretty good at finding and eliminating "dead code". Since you're not doing anything with the memory you allocate, there's a pretty decent chance that the optimizer is recognizing the allocation as dead code, so it simply eliminates it entirely.

Comment: You should use a profiler for this, if you're really into optimization you cannot rely on the wall-clock of your system and you should inspect the number of cpu cycles spent on something.

Comment: Also do NOT use std::chrono::high_resolution_clock (yes it is in the standard library but it should not have been, it usually picks std::system_clock which is not monotonic). Use std::chrono::stready_clock for measurements

Comment: @JerryCoffin I even tried to give a "meaning" to the allocated code, by assigning it certain values after the time measurement part of the code, and it still outputs 0 nanoseconds.

Comment: what do you mean stack space? this is memory from the heap, memory from new is not on the stack its from the heap

Comment: @UpAndAdam Yes, you are correct. I meant heap. Or I could use malloc() which allocates on stack.

Comment: Since value `p` is not used and compiler are quite smart, then if you enabled optimizations compiler is able to remove this allocations, meaning your code doesn't measure anything meaningful. Here is example where compiler did exactly that: https://godbolt.org/z/3GKoEPfWz it just calls time measurements twice in a row.

Comment: malloc does not allocate on the stack either it allocates from the heap. all dynamic memory allocation is from the heap.

Comment: What system are you using? Do you have HPET? What compiler are you using? I get ~80ns.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` for anything. Use `std::chrono::steady_clock`. From the creators mouth: [_What are the uses of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426832/what-are-the-uses-of-stdchronohigh-resolution-clock) - Short answer: There are none.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am using g++ compiler. My system is: Intel i3-1115G4 and memory 16000MB ram.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your CPU speed, actual time resolution and some other platform specifics the allocation can be that fast - faster than your hi-res timer resolution.

As it has been mentioned here, it is not allocation of physical storage. The memory is not actually reserved for your process immediately after you call `new[]`. It is only allocation within your process virtual memory space. That is why it is fast.

Depending on your platform, you may be able to use CPU hardware clock to measure the time more precisely. On x86 architecture there is RDTSC command which provides access to the CPU ticks counter. The problem with it is that modern CPUs change their clock speed depending on the load. Anyway, it is the most precise thing you could use. In C++ code it can be accessed through ASM block or through intrinsic functions like `__rdtsc()`. Here is the code specific to Visual Studio.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <intrin.h> // Platform specific, gives __rdtsc()

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

auto memory_allocation(size_t n) -> auto
{
    auto memory = new byte[n];
    return memory;
}

int main()
{
    // Estimate the best time clock resolution
    auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    decltype(t0) t1;
    do
    {
        t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    } while (t1 == t0);

    auto resolution = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t1 - t0);
    cout << "Time clock resolution: " << resolution << endl;

    for (size_t n = 0; n <= 1'000'000'000; n = n ? n * 10 : 1)
    {
        auto best_dx = numeric_limits<decltype(__rdtsc())>::max(); // the type is uint64
        auto best_ns = high_resolution_clock::duration::max();

        for (int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
        {
            auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto x = __rdtsc();

            auto p = memory_allocation(n);

            auto dx = __rdtsc() - x;
            auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

            delete[] p;

            auto ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t1 - t0);
            best_dx = min(best_dx, dx);
            best_ns = min(best_ns, ns);
        }

        cout << n << ", " << best_dx << ", " << best_ns << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the result from my machine:

```
Time resolution: 100ns
0, 72, 0ns
1, 72, 0ns
10, 90, 0ns
100, 290, 100ns
1000, 306, 100ns
10000, 306, 100ns
100000, 264, 100ns
1000000, 234, 100ns
10000000, 9242, 3200ns
100000000, 10462, 3600ns
1000000000, 22240, 7600ns
```