# No match for 'operator<<' const std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm trying to run this [cppreference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) for profiling my code:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <ratio>
#include <thread>
 
void f()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
 
int main()
{
    const auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f();
    const auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 
    // floating-point duration: no duration_cast needed
    const std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> fp_ms = t2 - t1;
 
    // integral duration: requires duration_cast
    const auto int_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
 
    // converting integral duration to integral duration of
    // shorter divisible time unit: no duration_cast needed
    const std::chrono::duration<long, std::micro> int_usec = int_ms;
 
    std::cout << "f() took " << fp_ms << ", or "
              << int_ms << " (whole milliseconds), or "
              << int_usec << " (whole microseconds)\n";
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
    >’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
         std::cout << "f() took " << fp_ms << ", or "
```

I'm passing `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++17` but no success.

I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`.

**Edit:**

Apparently, I need to pass -std=c++20 but my g++ version doesn't support it. The question is now how to get this feature or similar one for my g++ version.

Comment: int_ms.count() ? https://cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/duration_cast/

Comment: @KIIV, but I need to cast the output to double. Apparently, I need to pass `-std=c++20` but my g++ version doesn't support it.

Comment: Adding in a tag for Chrono to attract the eyes of chrono gurus who may know a good work-around. Maybe [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) can get you what you want in a pre C++20 world.

Comment: Speaking of Mr. Hinnant, here's something you should read: [What are the uses of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37426832/4581301)

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the link. I think it should be clear from the website about this info.

Comment: Are you really stuck with an antique (late 2019) version of GCC?

Comment: @Useless I'm using haptic device and I need to run their API in ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: why does that stop you from updating GCC?

Comment: @NathanOliver good point. I need to stick with whatever in the repository for Ubuntu 18.04. I need to avoid installing different versions.

Comment: heck, I'm stuck with 2004 version o GCC for certain devices and there is no way to update (CPUs aren't supported)

Comment: Ditto. I have a couple maintenance projects using GCC3.3 and a few using long-dead compilers for long-dead hardware platforms, one of which only runs properly in DOS 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `std::chrono` doesn't provide an implementation of `operator<<` for `std::chrono::duration` types [until C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_ltlt).

However, you can achieve much the same results with the C++17 or C++14 versions of the STL (and *probably* also with C++11) by using the `.count()` member function of that `duration` class. The equivalent output line for your code would look like this:

```cpp
std::cout << "f() took " << fp_ms.count() << ", or "
    << int_ms.count() << " (whole milliseconds), or "
    << int_usec.count() << " (whole microseconds)\n";
```

Alternatively, you could implement the relevant `operator<<` overload as a function template if the detected compilation standard is less than C++20. The following will allow your output code to be used *as is*:

```cpp
#if __cplusplus < 202002L
template <class rep, class period>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::chrono::duration<rep, period> value) {
    os << value.count();
    // Edited to check for (some) unit suffixes; you can others as you want ...
    if constexpr (std::is_same<std::micro, period>::value) os << "us";
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<std::milli, period>::value) os << "ms";
    else os << "s"; // ^^ Pre-C++17, you'll need to omit the "constexpr" keywords!
    return os;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Actually, I don't care much about `cout`. I need to save the elapsed time to file but same problem appears.

Comment: @CroCo Then, hopefully, you can readily adapt the code I have shown for your purpose; one output stream is much the same as another (in some ways).

Comment: So there is no hope to get the fractions and I need to stick with the int version of millisecond, right?

Comment: The code I showed gives the fractional part for the `<double, std::milli>` variable, and the function template will take both floating-point and integral types. In fact, my function template is really just a ***heavily*** trimmed-down version of the C++20 version implemented by MSVC (throwing out a lot of state checks).

Comment: @CroCo OK, I've added some sample suffixes (milliseconds and microseconds) to the function template.