# Is there a less verbose way of expressing duration in ms and hours?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, units-of-measurement, fmt

This C++ snippet prints a duration in ms and hours:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
  auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  this_thread::sleep_for(300ms);
  auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << duration<float, milli>{t1-t0}.count() << "\n";
  cout << duration<float, ratio<3600>>{t1-t0}.count() << "\n";
}
```

Is there a less cumbersome and more concise way of expressing this duration in various time units? `ratio<3600>` seems especially clunky. I'd rather have something with `hour` in it. Also, I prefer an option, which plays nicely with current `fmt` library (https://fmt.dev/10.2.0/). For example, `t1-t0` works fine with `iostream`, but not with `fmt`.

I've spent time looking at and experimenting with time units based on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration and all I got were numerous and long template barfs. No clue why someone decided that `duration<float, hour>` is not a good analog of `duration<float, milli>`.

Comment: What about just using aliases: https://godbolt.org/z/11jxEebYq

Comment: *why `duration<float, hour>` is not a good analog of `duration<float, milli>`* - "milli" is a standard SI prefix, like "micro", "kilo", etc., but "hour" has nothing to do with them. Similar to `std::chrono::hours`, you could define your own alias for `float` hour duration.

Comment: `using fhours = duration<float, hours::period>;`

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade I would rather stay with the standard and not create a mini-DSL.

Comment: @Evg Thank you. I misunderstood the meaning of `milli`. I thought it stood for `ms`.

Comment: @PaulJurczak so you are willing to use non-standard fmt library, but don't want to use a few aliases?... :/

Comment: Sidenote: To save you from some headscratching later, use `std::steady_clock` instead of `std::high_resolution_clock`. A `std::high_resolution_clock` is not guaranteed to be monotonic so it is allowed to go back in time. Don't use it for measuring durations. Edit: And just now I noticed @HowardHinnant :-)

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade `fmt` is in the standard C++23 as `format` and such. I'm using it because mainstream compilers are not fully implementing these standard features yet.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I need high precision time measurements. `high_resolution_clock` is the clock with the shortest tick period available. It takes a while for it to overflow.

Comment: What are the uses of `high_resolution_clock`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37440647/576911

Comment: @HowardHinnant I like `hours::period`, `minutes::period`, etc. It would be nice to have subsecond equivalents, e.g. `ms::period`, `ns::period`, etc. Even better just straight `hours`, `minutes`, `ms`, `ns`, etc., but that would probably need that smaller and simpler C++ to get born, or Carbon, or Sutter's cppfront...

Comment: You already have them: `std::chrono::milliseconds::period`, `std::chrono::nanoseconds::period`.

Comment: @PaulJurczak `period` is simply a `std::chrono::duration` typedef for the [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) in relation to seconds.

Comment: @PaulJurczak:  Perhaps a chrono tutorial would be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M. Cost: 1h.  It seems like you already know a lot of it.  But the tutorial might fill in some holes and design rationale.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Agree. It would have been a much better time investment than what I did with cppreference and a book or two :-(

Comment: _Side note:_ @Paul Jurczak wrote: _`fmt` is in the standard C++23 as `format` and such. _ `std::format` came in with C++20, so it may be more widely available than you thought. `std::print` entered with C++23.  That's the one that may still have only limited support.

Comment: @tbxfreeware I meant *<format>* not *format()*. And I care about *print()*, which, as you noted, is not yet available. I had no need for *format()* so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

chrono has [these aliases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) for integral representations:

- `std::chrono::milliseconds`
- `std::chrono::hours`

If you want a floating-point representation then you'll have to define similar aliases yourself, e.g.

```cpp
using float_milliseconds = std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>;
```

As suggested by Howard, for hours you can use `hours::period` which is more intuitive than `ratio<3600>`.

This can be done once and reused.

Both your durations work fine with the latest version of {fmt}: https://www.godbolt.org/z/ssorhqMPY.

Comment: Duration works fine, but I wrote: *t1-t0 works fine with iostream, but not with fmt*

Comment: Including *fmt/chrono.h* makes *t1-t0* work with *fmt*. Thank you.