# Efficient recovery of data array in C++ using pointer and size, and save result to csv

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have to save single channel image data to disk, preferably as a .CSV file.
Each pixel has a float value.
The data can be accessed using the following 3 parameters, provided by an event:

- Pointer to first element of array (unsigned short* thermal)
- Horizontal pixels (unsigned int w)
- Vertical pixels (unsigned int h)

For this I use the following code compiled with the default settings from Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, with optimization turned on (favoring speed).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    // Definitions
    float value;
    int w = 400;
    int h = 600;
    int size = h * w;
    // Generate array
    unsigned short dataArray[400*600];
    // Populate with data
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        dataArray[i] = (rand() % 1000);
    }
    // Create pointer to first element
    unsigned short* thermal = & dataArray[0];
    // Create csv file
    std::ofstream out("C:/Temp/test.csv");
    auto started = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
        {
            value = (*(thermal + (i * w) + (j * 1)))/ 10.0 + 100.0;
            out << value;
            if (j < (w - 1))
            {
                out << ";";
            }
        }
        out << '\n';
    }
    auto finished = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time elapsed line " << w << ": " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(finished - started).count() << "\n";
```

This does what it is intended to do, however it's very slow.
Saving an image of 480x765 pixels (±1.4MB) takes well over 2 seconds, while initially I expected it to only take a few milliseconds.
I have found that it does not make a difference to write to an intermediate string, even if I do a memory allocation of a certain size. The time for appending a value to the string does not appear to increase with the size of the string. This suggests that converting the values to string takes the majority of time. Is there another efficient way to generate a .CSV file with the requested data? Or is there any suggestion on what could be the limiting factor and how I can speed this up?

Comment: How are you compiling this code? What compiler and compilation flags are you using?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of the code and tell us how you measured the time and how you compiled the code

Comment: Possibly, `value = thermal[i * w + j] * 0.1f - 100.0f;` to save a conversion and a division. Most of the time is probably spent formatting numbers as text, though.

Comment: With C++17 came [std::to_chars()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars).

Comment: writing binary data rather than text is likely to be faster. Not only you save the cost of formatting the numbers, but you can also write bigger chunks of the data in one go

Comment: I have edited the code to include a reproducible example that shows the problem for a 400x600 array.

Comment: What compiler are you using and how do you compile the code with said compiler?

Comment: Are the "default settings" without optimization? Time measurements are pretty much meaningless if it is.

Comment: Optimization is turned on in the example. Turning optimization off increases the execution time by ±200ms.

Comment: @wvdk Looks like it takes less than 0.1 second on whatever VM godbolt runs on. https://godbolt.org/z/TT7nTYExP Are you saving to a slow or damaged hard drive, or network drive?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is a network drive on a virtual server. Might well be that this is the limiting factor! I will request to have more capacity allocated and run the code again.

Comment: running this with my VS2019 in release mode this code only takes me 208ms for the total execution.  I did do this test on an SSD.  I do not have a HDD to test against for that performance..  What kind of device are you storing this file on?

Comment: @wvdk Consider temporarily changing the output path to save to a local drive, just to see if it helps.

Comment: "It is a network drive on a virtual server." That's your time sink. Your numbers suggest that you're around ~5.5 MBit/s. If you want to save faster, you should probably talk to your IT people about bandwidth.

Comment: Side note: `high_resolution_clock` is specified to prize resolution above all else including stability and accuracy of that time. This makes it a bad option for timing. [More reading on the topic: What are the uses of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37426832/4581301)

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out by two contributors, code execution takes less than 100ms on the godbolt VM: https://godbolt.org/z/TT7nTYExP
This points to inadequate hardware and not a problem in the code.