# Incorrect Framerate Limitation in Program

Tags: c++, frame-rate

I am trying to limit the FPS in my program,
I also test the FPS to see if I actually limited it correctly,
but for some reason, I get incorrect values in my FPS

```cpp
int main()
{
    float cameraFps = 60;
    auto lastTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int targetFrameDurationMilli = 1000 / cameraFps;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        auto cycleStartTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            
        //Do some process
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));


        auto cycleEndTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto processingDurationMilli = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(cycleEndTime - cycleStartTime).count();


        if (processingDurationMilli < targetFrameDurationMilli) {
            auto sleepDurationMilli = targetFrameDurationMilli - processingDurationMilli;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleepDurationMilli));
        }

        // Measure total cycle time (processing + sleep) for accurate FPS calculation.
        cycleEndTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto cycleDurationMilli = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(cycleEndTime - lastTime);
        lastTime = cycleEndTime;

        double currentFPS = 1000.0 / cycleDurationMilli.count();
        std::cout << "Current FPS: " + std::to_string(currentFPS) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I created a small example,
I think I'm measing something super obvious here and it's driving me insane..

tried the code above, chat gpt and more eyes to look at

I get the following output:

```
*
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 34.482759
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 31.250000
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 34.482759
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 31.250000
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 34.482759
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 33.333333
Current FPS: 32.258065
Current FPS: 32.258065
*
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give us more details. Like what happens when you build it, do you get any warnings? If not, what happens if you enable more warnings? When it builds cleanly without warnings, even when enabling a lot of extra warnings, what happens when you run the program? What is the result? What is the expected result?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [What are the uses of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426832/what-are-the-uses-of-stdchronohigh-resolution-clock)

Comment: Oh, and please don't do `std::cout << "Current FPS: " + std::to_string(currentFPS) << std::endl;`... Do `std::cout << "Current FPS: " << currentFPS << '\n';` And remember that output to a terminal is usually rather slow.

Comment: Is 60Hz also the framerate on your display? If so wait for the vertical retrace. (how to do that is system specific).

Comment: And no matter if you want to print to the terminal, or on the graphical display, don't show the FPS *every* frame, it will vary wildly and take up too much time. For a graphical display, calculate an average and update two to four times a second. If writing to a terminal, do the same but only once a second.

Comment: Are you using windows? If so note that, by default, sleep's minimum duration is around 15ms.

Comment: Instead of slamming the terminal, bang together a basic OpenGL/DirectX/Vulkan window and throw text in there. That can do >1000FPS on even mid-range GPUs.

Comment: [`sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for): "Blocks the execution of the current thread for *at least* the specified sleep_duration." In principle, there is no limit to how long the sleep can be.