Which C++ time mechanism to use?
I'm trying to write a BW generator program that sends some fixed number of reads/writes every second and then sleeps for the rest of the time. Pseudocode:
for <number of iterations>
  milliseconds time = current_time;
  for i in <number of reads/writes>
    a = array[ptr+i]
    array[ptr+i] = 10
  milliseconds now = current_time;
  sleep(1000 - (now - time));

I'm trying to figure out which time library would be best suited for this. Higher precision would be nice but not a hard requirement as I can just run for more iterations to even out sub-millisecond variations.
std::chrono has 3 clocks: system_clock, steady_clock and high_resolution_clock (which I'm to understand can just be an alias of the previous 2?). I've attempted to use high_resolution_clock but the program is running for 200s when I've told it to run 100 iterations (should be 100 sec).
Any suggestions?

The std::chrono library typically has nanosecond precision.  If your results are off by billions of nanoseconds, your problem is likely something other than your choice of time library.  Can you show a [mre], rather than pseudocode?

FWIW, don't use std::chrono::high_resolution_clock: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426832/what-are-the-uses-of-stdchronohigh-resolution-clock

Given that you want the loop to be executed once per second, I wouldn't try to compute a interval to sleep at all (even if your system supports the non-standard [in C++] sleep() function).    I'd simply access the current time before the loop (e.g. using std::chrono::system_clock::now() or std::chrono::steady_clock::now()), add a specified delta to that (in your case one second), then use std::this_thread::sleep_until().   Bear in mind that, no matter what you do, there will be jitter in the sleep times, unless you use a realtime operating system.

Sleep until the next second.  Don't try to compute how long to sleep for.
milliseconds time = current_time;
for <number of iterations>
  for i in <number of reads/writes>
    a = array[ptr+i]
    array[ptr+i] = 10
  current_time += 1s;
  sleep until(current_time);

std::this_thread::sleep_until

I'd say steady_clock. You don't know what clock you are getting with high_resolution_clock (see the notes at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) and system_clock may go backwards.
